# PyCharm moves caret after line commenting

Tags: pycharm

I use PyCharm as Python IDE editor.

When I push default keyboard shortcut `ctrl+slash` to comment a line - caret (keyboard cursor) is moved to the next line (if text is not selected).

**There is a way to make caret stay on the same line?**

Comment: What's the purpose??

Comment: @Mr. Che, did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @Viragos No, unfortunately.

Comment: @R.A.Munna To stay on the same line. ;)

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś In PyCharm 2019.3.2 (Community Edition) `ctrl+slash` cursor stay on the same line. :) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In case you always want the action to keep caret on the same line, there's an option in 'Advanced Settings' - 'Move caret down after Comment with Line Comment action'.
>
> [image: img]
>
> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283756/Line-comment-shortcut-without-jumping-to-new-line

Comment: The dragon was defeated after six years.

Answer (score 0):

try for making caret stay in same line at very beginning of the line

```
shift + #
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, apparently there is still no way to disable this behaviour according to 
[this jetbrains support entry](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205819109-Disable-caret-moving-at-comment-hotkey). 
There is a workaround described:

> 1) Start with Edit | Macros | Start Macro Recording
>
> 2) Press "Ctrl" + "/" to comment out current line
>
> 3) Press "Up" to move caret to that line again
>
> 4) End with Edit | Macros | Stop Macro Recording

But if you apply this, selecting multiple lines to comment them out/in behaves different.  There are [two tickets in the Issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-461526) for this, but it doesn't seem to be worked on.

Highlighting a piece of text on the line and then doing the comment shortcut is the closest non-breaking fix I could find...